# How do I create columns in modals?

Tags: html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I looked on the bootstrap site and the code just isn't working with my PHP. Here is the code...I am trying to place the image in one column, and the title and content in the second column so there is no need to scroll. It is putting everything into one skinny column instead of two.

```
         <div class="modal fade" id="person-<?php echo $n; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="person-<?php echo $n; ?>Label" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="person-<?php echo $n; ?>Label"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="person-<?php echo $n; ?>">
                            <div class="col-4, col-sm-6">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class'=>'img-fluid team-image')); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-8, col-sm-6">
                                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Seems more like an HTML/CSS issue than a PHP issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns in modals work the same like in other HTML, when properly used. In your example there is no `.col` div inside the `.row` div.

Move the content to two separate `div.col` columns like this:

```
<div class="row" id="person-<?php echo $n; ?>">
    <div class="col">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class'=>'img-fluid team-image')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

More about bootstrap grid here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: I'm sorry...I did do that, but all it did was put everything into one long skinny column. I did col-4 around the thumbnail, and col-8 around the title and content...

Comment: You have to put the `.col` as a direct child of a `.row` (`.row` > `.col`). Remove the `<div id="person-<?php echo $n; ?>">` and also its closing tag

Comment: Oh duh :) thank you! (This is my first site...if you couldn't tell)